# Make x axis values the same as series

Tags: apexcharts

Is it possible to show on x axis only series data?
For example, I have serie:

```
"data":[{"x":70000,"y":6.5354E7}, {{"x":71000,"y":5.5354E7}} ....]
```

I want only supplied x values on x axis. On default settings, values on axis even have fractions.

I tried to play with different options, but without any success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use categories to have complete control over the values that are shown in the labels of the X axis. The official documentation has a lot of examples with text labels but there's nothing preventing you from using numbers either. They're just labels.

Instead of having:

```js
let options = {
  series: [
    {
      data: [{"x":70000,"y":6.5354E7}, {"x":71000,"y":5.5354E7}]
    }
  ]
  ...
};
```

You would have:

```js
let options = {
  series: [
    {
      data: [{"x":1,"y":6.5354E7}, {"x":2, "y":5.5354E7}]
    }
  ],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [70000, 71000]
  }
  ...
};
```

You can automate this by iterating over every point and storing every unique x value into an array. Here's an example that does just that:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>

<script>
function createCategories(series) {
  let unique = new Set();

  // Collects unique x coordinates.
  for (let serie of series) {
    for (let point of serie.data) {
      unique.add(point.x);
    }
  }


  // Creates categories
  let categories = Array.from(unique);

  // Sorts categories ascendantly.
  categories.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  return categories;
}

function replaceXCoordinatesWithCategories(series, categories) {
  for (let serie of series) {
    for (let point of serie.data) {
      point.x = categories.indexOf(point.x) + 1;
    }
  }
}

let series = [
  {
    data: [
      { x: 71000, y: 3.5354E7 },
      { x: 72000, y: 2.5354E7 },
      { x: 73000, y: 1.5354E7 },
      { x: 74000, y: 5.5354E7 },
      { x: 75000, y: 4.5354E7 },
      { x: 76000, y: 4.5354E7 },
    ]
  },
  {
    data: [
      { x: 71000, y: 6.5354E7 },
      { x: 72000, y: 5.5354E7 },
      { x: 73000, y: 4.5354E7 },
      { x: 74000, y: 3.5354E7 },
      { x: 75000, y: 2.5354E7 },
    ]
  }
];

let categories = createCategories(series);
replaceXCoordinatesWithCategories(series, categories);

let options = {
  series: series,
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'line'
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: categories
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
</script>
```

Comment: I tied your method, it works, but data updates break it completely :( (I'm computing new categories after data receive, but when I update options, XAxis shows X entries (1, 2, 3) as if it's reverted from category mode.